# Arguments must have same length when using tapply

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data.frame(q1 = sample(c(1, 5), 200, replace = T, prob = c(1/2, 1/2)), 
           gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 200, replace = T, prob = c(2/3, 1/3)) 
           ) %>% tapply(.$q1,list(.$gender),FUN=sum)
```

I just want to use `tapply` to `sum` by `gender`, but got error as below:

> Error in tapply(., .$q1, list(.$gender), FUN = sum) : 
>         arguments must have same length

Where's the problem?

Comment: `tapply(df$q1, df$gender, sum)` works Or if you want to use it with pipes you might need to do `df %>% {tapply(.$q1,list(.$gender),FUN=sum)}`

Comment: @RonakShah,what's the usage of  this `{}`?

Comment: By default LHS of pipe is the first argument to the function on RHS, so by using `{}` we avoid that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For the sum example, you can use `data.table` syntax:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(q1 = sample(c(1, 5), 200, replace = T, prob = c(1/2, 1/2)), 
                 gender = sample(c("M", "F"), 200, replace = T, prob = c(2/3, 1/3)))
as.data.table(df)[, sum(q1), by = gender]
```

This will also work with a function that has multiple return values, unlike my previous example with `summarize`:

```
as.data.table(df)[, shapiro.test(q1), by = gender]
```

Comment: If the function is not `sum`,but some else like `shapiro.test`,is `summarize(shapiro.test(q1))`  workable?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, summarize works for a single return value